# How to compare and match data from different columns of same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i am new to programming and trying to learn python. pardon me if this sounds silly. i am trying to compare two columns in a dataframe and match the values based on the first column(used as reference). when the values in first column are not available in second or third columns, then i need to enter an NaN. could anyone helpme out how to do this? please look at the input and expected output below

Input dataframe:

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 290 | 390 | 160 |
| 1 | 390 | 450 | 290 |
| 2 | 160 | 290 | NaN |
| 3 | 450 | NaN | 450 |

Expected Output

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 290 | 290 | 290 |
| 1 | 390 | 390 | NaN |
| 2 | 160 | NaN | 160 |
| 3 | 450 | 450 | 450 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[290, 390, 160],[390, 450, 290], [160, 290, np.NaN], [450, np.NaN, 450]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

lis = list(df['A'])
print(lis)
```

**Output**

```
[290, 390, 160, 450]
```

Then

```
b = [i if i in list(df['B']) else np.nan for i in lis]
c = [i if i in list(df['C']) else np.nan for i in lis]
print(b)
print(c)
```

Output

```
[290, 390, nan, 450] #b
[290, nan, 160, 450] #c
```

Replace the column B,C with list b and c

```
df = df.assign(B=b)
df = df.assign(C=c)
```

| index | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 290 | 290 | 290 |
| 1 | 390 | 390 | NaN |
| 2 | 160 | NaN | 160 |
| 3 | 450 | 450 | 450 |